# React router link messes up MUI tab component styling

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router, styling

I'm having certain styling for the `<Tab>` component from MUI and currently I'm wrapping this tab with a `<Link>` from `react-router-dom`.  The `<Tab>` has some styling which handles the active tab etc. but the Link messes this up.

What is the cleanest way to make sure the `<Link>` styling gets removed and it displays the `<Tab>` styling instead?

Code is as follow:

```
<Link to='/app/listings'>
   <Tab value="one" icon={<FormatListBulletedIcon />} label="Challenges" iconPosition='start' />
</Link>`
```

edit:

The `<Tab>` is styled in my MUI Theme as followed:

```
components: {
        MuiTab: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    minHeight:24,
                    fontSize: 12,
                    padding: '6px 10px',
                    justifyContent: 'flex-start'
                },
            },
        },
   },
```

The `<Link` tag wrapping it overwrites this.

Simple example: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-framework-u01mdk?file=/src/App.js

Remove the Link tag and styling changes.

Comment: Do you mean something *other then* the `className` or `style` props? You didn't provide much code to go from, so it's probably going to be difficult to provide more specific help. Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve] that includes the current styling that is applied, and what exactly is getting "messed up" and what you want changed?

Comment: @DrewReese Edited it, there's not much other styling there to mention. Basically the Link tag is overwriting the styling of the Tab component.

Comment: Think you could throw together a small [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: @DrewReese Sure, here's a quick sandbox displaying the issue. https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-framework-u01mdk?file=/src/App.js if you remove the Link tag the styling changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render the `Tab` component ***as*** a `Link`.

Instead of

```
<Link color="inherit" to="/app/listings">
  <Tab
    value="one"
    icon={<FormatListBulletedIcon />}
    label="Challenges"
    iconPosition="start"
  />
</Link>
```

[image]

use the `Tab` component's `component` prop to really render the `Link` component and pass all the link props to the `Tab`.

```
<Tab
  component={Link}
  color="inherit"
  to="/app/listings"
  value="one"
  icon={<FormatListBulletedIcon />}
  label="Challenges"
  iconPosition="start"
/>
```

[image]

Comment: That works great! Didn't realize it renders the actual tab as a link. Thank you.

Comment: @WesleyvanS Welcome, glad to help. Another alternative is the `label` prop takes a `node`, so you could potentially render the `Link` there, but then it'd still have its own style (*blue and underlined IIRC*) and only the label would effect a navigation actions, the tab would just be the tab. Using the `Tab` `component` prop is clearly better in this use case. Cheers and good luck!